# Can you add 2 types of items to the stggeredListView?

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

My app uses

> com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView

and i have an adapter that populates the staggered grid with a custom item. I now want to add another custom item to that grid. Can this be done?

I have 2 custom item xmls and 2 layoutadapters. How can I add both to the staggeredgrid? I tried using addVeiw() but its not available in staggeredGridview. Maybe i should only be using 1 adapter?

Ill keep the code to a minimum but ask if you want to see more.

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

public class GamesSummary_Fragment_Activity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private ArrayList<String[]> loginTilesData;
    private static final String TAG = "StaggeredGridActivityFragment";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            final StaggeredGridFragment fragment = new StaggeredGridFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    private class StaggeredGridFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener
    {
                private StaggeredGridView stagggeredGridView;
                private boolean mHasRequestedMore;
                private TilesAdapter_Summary mAdapter;

                @Override
                public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setRetainInstance(true);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sgv, container, false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    //Encapsulate all within a post create from a async task or call a blocking http call
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                    stagggeredGridView = (StaggeredGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

                    if (mAdapter == null) {
                        mAdapter = new TilesAdapter_Summary(getActivity(), R.id.summary1_value);
                    }

                    for (String[] data : loginTilesData) {
                        mAdapter.add(data); //Add each loginTilesData TileAdapter element to an mAdapter where it will be further broken down and used by the TileAdapter
                    }
                //Add controls item layout
                final LayoutInflater layoutInflator = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                View viewControls = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_controls, null);
                staggeredGridView.addView(viewControls, 1); //THIS FAILS WITH ERROR SAYING PARENT CLASS CANT DO 'addVeiw()

                    stagggeredGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    stagggeredGridView.setOnScrollListener(this);
                    stagggeredGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                }
}

public class TilesAdapter_Summary extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {
    private static final String TAG = "TilesAdapter";

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView summary_image;
        TextView summary1_label;
        TextView summary2_label;

    }
```

adapter_summary class

```
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private final Random mRandom;
    private final ArrayList<Integer> mBackgroundColors;
    private static final SparseArray<Double> sPositionHeightRatios = new SparseArray<Double>();

    public TilesAdapter_Summary(final Context context, final int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mRandom = new Random();
        mBackgroundColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        mBackgroundColors.add(R.color.green);
        mBackgroundColors.add(R.color.blue);
        mBackgroundColors.add(R.color.yellow);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
                //Init the Viewholder with the controls we want to populate
            ViewHolder vh;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_summary, parent, false);
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                vh.summary_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary_image);
                vh.summary1_label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary1_label);
                vh.summary2_label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary2_label);

                convertView.setTag(vh);
            } else {
                vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            double positionHeight = getPositionRatio(position);
            int backgroundIndex = position >= mBackgroundColors.size() ?
                    position % mBackgroundColors.size() : position;

            convertView.setBackgroundResource(mBackgroundColors.get(backgroundIndex));

            Log.d(TAG, "getView position:" + position + " h:" + positionHeight);

            String[] tileControlValues = getItem(position); //Get this TileAdapters item and split it up

            //Assign the tileControlValues to controls
            vh.summary_header.setText(tileControlValues[0]);
            vh.summary_subheader.setText(tileControlValues[1]);
            vh.summary1_label.setText(tileControlValues[2]);
            vh.summary1_value.setText(tileControlValues[3]);
            vh.summary2_label.setText(tileControlValues[4]);
            vh.summary2_value.setText(tileControlValues[5]);

        return convertView;
    }

    private double getPositionRatio(final int position) {
        double ratio = sPositionHeightRatios.get(position, 0.0);
        // if not yet done generate and stash the columns height
        // in our real world scenario this will be determined by
        // some match based on the known height and width of the image
        // and maybe a helpful way to get the column height!
        if (ratio == 0) {
            ratio = getRandomHeightRatio();
            sPositionHeightRatios.append(position, ratio);
            Log.d(TAG, "getPositionRatio:" + position + " ratio:" + ratio);
        }
        return ratio;
    }

    private double getRandomHeightRatio() {
        return (mRandom.nextDouble() / 2.0) + 1.0; // height will be 1.0 - 1.5 the width
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the type of the problem you are trying to solve, a good suitable alternative would be to consider utilizing RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager and customizing the adapter to work with 2 (or more if required) types of ViewHolders, allowing each one of them to have it's own layout.

Update:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if(getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
        // work with ViewHolderTypeOne
    } else if(getItemViewType(position) == 2) {
        // work with ViewHolderTypeTwo
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int i) {
    // View Types: 1 - view type one, 2 - view type two, determined by position i in grid
    if(i == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

class ViewHolderTypeOne extends ViewHolder {
    public viewOneAttrOne;
    public viewOneAttrTwo;
}

class ViewHolderTypeTwo extends ViewHolder {
    public viewTwoAttrOne;
    public viewTwoAttrTwo;
    public viewTwoAttrThree;
}
```

Comment: oh dear, im way too deep for recycler view to be a trivial chaneg :( Is there anyway using staggered view i could do this  - im currenty invesigating having one adapter that, pending a switch, referes to one item xml or the other

Comment: could you please also show the content of TilesAdapter_Summary class?

Comment: Sure... coming up....let me know if you want my sumary layout xml and the new layout xml; 'controls'

Comment: I am now looking at having a switch in adapter and pointing to diff xms based on thaty swicth passed from activity but this doesnt help as i only init the adapter once and so never get to add second item. I want to add one instance of my new custom view tot he grid after the summary tiles have been added

Comment: i could merge the views i suppose; showing what i want and hiding others to give appearance of 2 views but its not very satisfactory

Comment: Based on what I currently see in the adapter and your answer provided below, you might make your a bit more readable by extending from ViewHolder class and making 2 types of ViewHolders for your 2 types of layouts.

Comment: Hmmm can u put an answer down extrapolating that out a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer, not necessarily the best one so il leave it open for a bit...

I added merged the new item xml controls into the older one and so only have one, then i work out which controls to show when adding the item to the grid. Giving impression of 2 diff items in the one grid....when adding the items to the page...I add a new element to the string array that triggers a new item xml to be built - i recognize that this new element wants to show diff controls and so i take the original controls invisible and the new ones visible,

```
    if (tileControlValues[0].equals("controls"))
    {
        vh.layout_summary.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        vh.layout_controls.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        vh.summary_header.setText(tileControlValues[0]);
        vh.summary_subheader.setText(tileControlValues[1]);
        vh.summary1_label.setText(tileControlValues[2]);
        vh.summary1_value.setText(tileControlValues[3]);
        vh.summary2_label.setText(tileControlValues[4]);
        vh.summary2_value.setText(tileControlValues[5]);
```

Comment: Update to this, make the visibility set to View.Gone' to completely free up the space once used for the controls that you want invisible.